# webbugs like behavior to send specific and general info to server

Tags: javascript, cookies, server

I have been finding solutions for one technique that I need in my web app. All the big websites have that solution implemented.

Like Facebook, when user is logged in, and then that user open another tab, and go to xyz website. And that website say has facebook script on it. I have observed that without doing anything on xyz website (just visiting), Facebook ads are tuned related to the user being visited to xyz website.

I know webbugs can send data such as IP of user who is visiting xyz website but how come the specific information is also sent to facebook that facebook uses to tune ads experience for specific user. Specific action may be like, if I go to Qatar Airways website and search for flights from destination A to B then on Facebook I get ads related to deals on Qatar Airways from A to B.

How its technically possible? to me it seems like connecting two cookies. Or what else is possible? I need steps that I need to take to configure my server and client to achieve this functionality. And also what I need to do on other websites that user visits. Thanks

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score -1):

IP Addresses ,
HTTP Referrer ,
**Cookies & Tracking Scripts** ,
Super Cookies , 
User Agent .

steps : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: so does that mean website xyz has facebook analytics embeded? Or you didnt read my question?

Comment: " Like Facebook, when user is logged in, and then that user open another tab, and go to xyz website. **And that website say has facebook script on it** I have observed that without doing anything on xyz website (just visiting), Facebook ads are tuned related to the user being visited to xyz website. "